# Can you filter news sites that Bing News pulls from?

Tags: bing

Can sites that are used to pull information for Bing News be filtered out?

Suppose I have Video Games listed as an interest, but I don't want to see articles from Kotaku.com. Can that site's pages be blacklisted either through the phone interface or through Cortana's notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforunately you cannot do that.

The Bing news app has a list of main news sources which you can alter but the contents under the 'topics' tab does not have a source filter.

Comment: By this, do you mean that I can remove sites from the list of those Microsoft checks, but I cannot remove them on a per topic basis? i.e., if I remove kotaku.com from the list, it will be removed from all topics?

Comment: Changing the sources for the main 'news' feeds has no impact on any 'topics' you may have added.  There is no way to choose (or remove) providers from the 'topics' page.